# programmatically upload file to website and capture output

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am writing a WPF app in C# that (in the background) goes to a URL, uploads a .svg file and obtains the vector/xaml output and displays it on the screen.

Lets say the .svg file path on local machine is

> C:\Users\Me\Desktop\pic.svg

I need a method that would take the file and upload it to

> http://a-student.github.io/SvgToVectorDrawableConverter.Web/

And then capture the output displayed on the webpage into a string or any other similar format to be displayed in TextBlock on my WPF app.

I need help with only uploading and capturing result. I have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [WebClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx) class to do this pretty easily. Check out the [UploadFile()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36s52zhs(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

Comment: I am getting "The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed". Is there a solution to this?

Comment: The server doesn't like what you're sending it. Assuming your site works fine in a web browser, that means your program is doing something wrong. I suggest downloading the Fiddler web proxy to inspect and compare the POST/PUT requests from your manual interaction and from running your program.

Comment: Is it possible the owner/programmer of the site has blocked/disabled uploading files programmatically?

Comment: That's possible, but the error code suggests either a misconfigured site or a misbehaving program. Why don't you use the offline version that the online version is based on? It's written in C#. The link to the C# version is labeled "based on the powerful batch converter". See: https://github.com/a-student/SvgToVectorDrawableConverter

Comment: Thanks. The error i was getting was because i was trying to upload on the main site instead of the location when the file is uploaded when i do through web browser UI. I opened Inspect page and found the link behind the upload button and tried uploading there and got back the result i needed.